# rivets.js trying to get custom adapter to work

Tags: javascript, model-binding, rivets.js

I am trying to get a custom adapter to work with rivets.js, but it neither changes the model nor does it ever call the routine. If there's someone out there who is also using rivets.js, I could use some help with this one:

[JsFiddle Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/mtkastner/v5mtp3jo/)

```js
var menuContext = {
  menu: {
    watchList: {
      status: false,
      view: function() {
        // call other view
      }
    },
    profile: {
      status: false,
      view: function() {
        // call other view
      }
    }
  }
};

rivets.binders['on-select-item'] = {

  bind: function(el) {

    var adapter = rivets.adapters[rivets.rootInterface];
    var model = this.model;
    var keypath = this.keypath;
    var that = this;
    this.callback = function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var value = adapter.get(model, keypath);

      var newValue = !value;

      adapter.set(model, keypath, newValue);

    };
    el.addEventListener('click', this.callback);
  },
  unbind: function(el, value) {
    el.removeEventListener('click', this.callback);
  },
  routine: function(el, value) {

    console.log('I am only being called once!');
  
    value ? el.classList.add('enabled') : el.classList.remove('enabled');
  }
};

var menu = document.querySelector("#menu");


rivets.bind(menu, menuContext);
```

```css
#menu .enabled {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mikeric/rivets/master/dist/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" rv-on-select-item="menu.watchList.status">
    Item 1, value should toggle (true|false) <span rv-html="menu.watchList.status"></span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" rv-on-select-item="menu.profile.status">
        Item 2, value value should toggle (true|false) <span rv-html="menu.profile.status"></span>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `keypath` here is the full path string you specify in your template, but your model here is the object holding the last property in `keypath` (*don't ask me why, that's how it's when debugging*) and looking at the [source code of default adapter](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/blob/master/dist/rivets.js#L1370), it doesn't seem to be doing any traversal:

```
get: function(obj, keypath) {
  return obj[keypath];
},
set: function(obj, keypath, value) {
  return obj[keypath] = value;
}
```

So you'll have to resolve the `keypath` by yourself. Something like the following will do in this case:

```js
var menuContext = {
  menu: {
    watchList: {
      status: false,
      view: function() {
        // call other view
      }
    },
    profile: {
      status: false,
      view: function() {
        // call other view
      }
    }
  }
};

rivets.binders['on-select-item'] = {

  bind: function(el) {
    var adapter = rivets.adapters[rivets.rootInterface];
    var model = this.model;
    var keypath = this.keypath;
    var that = this;
    this.callback = function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var key = keypath.split('.').slice(-1);
      var value = adapter.get(model, key);
      var newValue = !value;
      adapter.set(model, key, newValue);
    };
    el.addEventListener('click', this.callback);
  },
  unbind: function(el, value) {
    el.removeEventListener('click', this.callback);
  },
  routine: function(el, value) {

    console.log('I am only being called once!');

    value ? el.classList.add('enabled') : el.classList.remove('enabled');
  }
};

var menu = document.querySelector("#menu");


rivets.bind(menu, menuContext);
```

```css
#menu .enabled {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mikeric/rivets/master/dist/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" rv-on-select-item="menu.watchList.status">
    Item 1, value should toggle (true|false) <span rv-html="menu.watchList.status"></span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" rv-on-select-item="menu.profile.status">
        Item 2, value value should toggle (true|false) <span rv-html="menu.profile.status"></span>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I know you're following the two way binding [example](http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#binders-two-way) at official site, but the library seem to have got major updates since. If you want to know "why" better place would be the [github repo](https://github.com/mikeric/rivets) where the author could give some insights.